# Algorithm for calculating substitution combination with ordering

Tags: ds.algorithms, permutations, combinatory-logic

I need to calculate the combinations of elements with a substitution element.

For example for elements `[A,B]` if the substitution is X the results should be `{[A,X],[X,B],[X,X]}`. While this is easy enough to implement when the number of elements increase it becomes harder and error prone.

Is there an algorithm I can implement for this kind of combination calculations?

If this question is not a good fit for this site I do apologize, but this is the best site for an algorithmic question as far as I can tell.

EDIT :

I should have mentioned that all results should be of the same length as well.

Comment: This is the same as picking a subset and replacing the elements in the subset with X.

Comment: Make that an answer, I can work from there, thank you.

Comment: This seems more suitable for [cs.se] which has a broader scope, for the scope of [cstheory.se] please check [about] and [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as picking a subset and replacing the elements in the subset with X